# Opening xlsx file using python wtforms openpyxl - error

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl, bottle, wtforms

im developing web application in python with Bottle. i want to upload xlsx file to load data from it. i uses openpyxl to do this but i get an error

```
import wtforms
import openpyxl
from bottle import request, route, run, view,
```

my form:

```
class UploadForm(wtforms.Form):
    file = wtforms.FileField()
```

View:

```
@route("/upload/file", method=['GET', 'POST'])
@view("upload")
def upload_file():
    form = UploadForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST)
        if form.validate():
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(form)
    return {'form': form}
```

templates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/skeleton.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/upload/file" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ !form.file.label }}
        {{ !form.file }}
        <div class="row">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/home/wojjak/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
return route.call(**args)
    File "/home/wojjak/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bottle.py", line 1740, in wrapper
rv = callback(*a, **ka)
    File "/home/wojjak/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bottle.py", line 3639, in wrapper
result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/home/wojjak/PycharmProjects/untitled/parsowanie.py", line 84, in upload_file
if form.validate():
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 171, in load_workbook
archive = _validate_archive(filename) 
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 91, in _validate_archive
if not is_file_like and os.path.isfile(filename):  
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 37, in isfile
st = os.stat(path)
    TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, UploadForm found
```

Any one know how to solve this

EDIT:

Ok. I solved it

```
def upload_file():
form = UploadForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadForm(request.POST)
    if form.file.data:
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(request.files[form.file.name].file)
```

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace. We can't see what line the error is on.

Comment: The error is fairly self-explanatory. You will need to extract the file from the form and pass it to openpyxl to open.